# Is Google Docs free for business use?

Tags: google-docs

Google Apps for business use [costs](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/features.html), but as far as I can tell Google Docs is free for business use. In the Google documentation on the topic, it just seems to state that it's free, full stop (I can't find the page I read that on, sorry).

However, in the Google Docs section of Google Apps, [there is a "free trial" offered](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/docs.html), which seems to imply that it's not free (though it could just be a marketing tactic!).

Can anyone confirm whether or not Google Docs is free for business use?

Answer (score 2):

The new [EULA](http://www.google.com/policies/terms/) (effective March 1) only states that

> Business uses of our Services
>
> If you are using our Services on behalf of a business, that business
>   accepts these terms. It will hold harmless and indemnify Google and
>   its affiliates, officers, agents, and employees from any claim, suit
>   or action arising from or related to the use of the Services or
>   violation of these terms, including any liability or expense arising
>   from claims, losses, damages, suits, judgments, litigation costs and
>   attorneys’ fees.

Otherwise, they reserve the right to limit the activity on any of their free services for any reason at all. You would be safer, if your needs are suited to that of a business in terms of activity, by using [google apps for business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) to ensure you don't lose any business-critical data.